# Nautical miles conversion problems

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a system that outputs this:

**Position in Cartesian Co-ordinates**

Definition: Position of a target in Cartesian co-ordinates, in twos complement form.

X-Component **7275**  ()    2^(-6+f) where f is the scaling factor applied, modifying the standard quantisation unit. Max. range = 2(9+f) NM

Y-Component **10628**  ()   2^(-6+f) Max. range = 2^(9+f) NM

NOTES 
1. A default quantisation unit of 1/64 NM is obtained for a value of f = 0.
2. Negative values are expressed in 2's complement form, bit-32 and bit-16 shall be set to 0 for positive values and 1 for negative values.

I want to visualize that position in **OpenLayers** but I don`t know how to transfort this in a way to match **OpenLayers** standarts.

How to do this?

Comment: Are these values coming from AIS? Is the output in lat/lon or UTM, do you know?

Comment: its from asterix protocol cat001 [link](http://www.eurocontrol.int/services/specifications-documents) and I don`t know what exactly are the values. I think its in meters distanse from the radar but I can`t be sure

Comment: Oh goodness, I had a look at that spec, it isn't very clear what coordinate system is used. I'm sorry, I can give you advice on transforming from one coordinate system to another in OpenLayers and on things like wms, but I really can't figure out much from that link.